# Why VSCode doesn't find code symbols even though the code parsed by intellisense?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have C project in WSL (same problem in "normal" windows).
I open the folder in VSCode and I have the C/C++ extension installed.

[image]

In .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json I have the "compilerPath" defined.

[image]

Whenever I do Ctrl+O and search for a symbol, VScode doesn't find it. If I open the file containing the symbol this search works (obviously).

I also tried using the command "C/C++: Reset IntelliSense Database" and it says it finished parsing but it didn't help.

[image]

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: you'll need to add system include paths to your intellisense configuration. Check your source files for intellisense errors

Comment: I have include path setup, also added "/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/arm-none-eabi/include/**", it didn't change anything.
I have include error, such as "cannot open source file "cygwin/config.h" (dependency of "ctype.h" though I don't see any reference to cygwin anywhere (and I don't use it). regardless intellisense doesn't recognizes any symbols not just system symbols

Comment: Odd thing, ctrl+click config.h (with red underline error mark) opens the file, I keep clicking all file links from this point and vscode find all of them, finally it reemoved the include error, why do I have to do that (open the files) for it to recognize them?